# how to trigger a function by pressing enter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this button that leads to a method in javascript that filters the information of a table:

```
<button type="button" id="search" title="Buscar" onclick="fn_cliente.filtraInformacion();"></button>
```

There are several fields for which you can filter the information, I want that when pressing "enter" on any input, it executes the same method as when clicking on the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following to bind the enter event to your search fields.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.searchfield').forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) filtraInformacion();
  });
});
```

## Look at this code snippet

```js
function filtraInformacion() {
  console.log('filtraInformacion has been called!');
}

document.querySelectorAll('.searchfield').forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) filtraInformacion();
  });
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="search" title="Buscar" onclick="filtraInformacion();">Click me</button>
<br>
<input id='name' class='searchfield' placeholder='Press Enter!'>
<br>
<input id='lastname' class='searchfield' placeholder='Press Enter!'><br>
<input id='gender' class='searchfield' placeholder='Press Enter!'>
```

See? when the enter key is pressed, the function `filtraInformacion` is called.

Comment: Yes, that works for me, but I have 6 inputs with which you can filter, I would have to do the same with each one?

Comment: I have a little question... I try to add this:  document.querySelectorAll('.search').forEach(function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13){ fn_cliente.filtraInformacion(); }
    if (e.keyCode === 27){
        document.querySelectorAll('.search').value = '';
        fn_cliente.filtraInformacion();    
    } 
  });
});

Comment: so that when "esc" is pressed, the input is deleted and the table is loaded without filters, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This works. You can adapt it to whatever element you want.

```
<input type="text" id="account-location-country-input" class="mdc-text-field__input" required onkeyup = "if (event.keyCode == 13)document.getElementById('edit-account-button').click()">
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but I have 6 inputs with which you can filter, I would have to do the same with each one?

Comment: Yes. You could script it but this is how I do it.